# Time and space complexity of base conversion code

Tags: python, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have an algorithm that performs the base conversion. The input is a string and two ints b1 and b2. The string represents an int in base b1 and converts it into base in b2.

My code is:

```
def convert_base(num_as_string, b1, b2):
    if num_as_string == '0' or num_as_string == '-0':
        return num_as_string
    base10, degree = 0, 0
    is_neg = False
    if num_as_string[0] == '-':
        is_neg, num_as_string = True, num_as_string[1:]
    if b1 == 10:
        base10 = int(num_as_string)
    else:
        for digit in num_as_string[::-1]:
            base10 += string.hexdigits.index(digit.lower()) * (b1 ** degree)
            degree += 1
    if b2 == 10:
        return '-' + str(base10) if is_neg else str(base10)
    converted = []
    while base10 > 0:
        digit = base10 % b2
        converted.append(digit)
        base10 //= b2
    res = ''
    for i in converted[::-1]:
        res += string.hexdigits[i].upper()
    return '-' + res if is_neg else res
```

Now I am trying to see if this can be improved in terms of time and space complexity. But I am not sure how to analyze the complexity of this code.

I know everything is constant before `for digit in num_as_string[::-1]:`. In this loop, it's just `O(n) where n is just number of digits of the input.

Then in `while base10 > 0`, it runs the look while `base10` becomes 0. So, this would be something like `O(number of digits in base10)`

Finally, on `for i in converted[::-1]`, this would also be `O(number of digits in base10)`.

So, I am assuming the time complexity of this code is something like `O(n) + 2 * O(number of digits in base10)` which is linear.

For space, I am assuming it's `O(number of digits in base10)` because I store it in `converted` list.

Are my observations correct? If not, what am I missing? Also, can this code be improved in terms of time and space complexity?

Thanks

Comment: Not directly related to question: the max base that the code can handle is 16?

Comment: @CristiFati Yes. We assume that `b1` and `b2` are between 2 and 16 inclusive.

Comment: Maybe a better forum for this Kind of question would be https://codereview.stackexchange.com/